# Can we allow an API to work using MessagePattern and Rest method as well in NestJS?

Tags: microservices, nestjs

I have a BFF needs to send some requests to ServiceA.

ServiceA is providing some API (GET, POST, ...) that we can deal with.
For example:

```
  @Get('greeting')
  getGreetingMessage(@Param('name') name: string): string {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
  }
```

In MicroService Architecture in NestJs I see the best practice in BFF to send requests to other servcies is to use Message patterns like `cmd` with payloads.
For example

```
  constructor(
    @Inject('SERVICE_A') private readonly clientServiceA: ClientProxy,
  ) {}

  getGreetingFromServiceA() {
    const startTs = Date.now();
    const pattern = { cmd: 'greeting' };
    const payload = {};
    return this.clientServiceA
      .send<string>(pattern, payload)
      .pipe(
        map((message: string) => ({ message, duration: Date.now() - startTs })),
      );
  }
```

So to do that I have to support MessagePattern in ServiceA like:

```
  @MessagePattern({cmd: 'greeting'})
  getGreetingMessage(name: string): string {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
  }
```

So my question is Is there a way to append MessagePattern to exisiting APIs in ServiceA? so I can call them with 2 different ways either by Rest GET Request or MessagePattern from BFF.
I'm thinking about using 2 docerators (Get and MessagePattern)
Like that

```
  @Get('greeting')
  @MessagePattern({cmd: 'greeting'})
  getGreetingMessage(@Param('name') name: string): string {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
  }
```

If no, so how can I use a proxyClient to make http requests to other microservice in the BFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not possible in NestJS to define more than one decorator to the same method in the controller but we make it a hybrid application which supports different communication protocols so we can call it via TCP or HTTP and so on like in this example https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application